# owa_util.redirect_url not working after apex upgrade to 5.1.1

Tags: oracle, upgrade, oracle-apex

We are using the below code to redirect the page

```
Owa_Util.Redirect_Url('f?p='|| V('APP_ID') || ':106:' || V('APP_SESSION'));
```

After upgrade from 3.2 to 5.1.1 this functionality is not working. As suggested from other post i have tried using

```
:FSP_AFTER_LOGIN_URL := ('f?p='||v('APP_ID')||':106:'||v('APP_SESSION'));
```

But this is only working inside the application(authentication scheme), In some code we are using `Owa_Util.Redirect_Url` in some procedure inside the packages.i suppose I can't use FSP_AFTER_LOGIN_URL there or can i? How should i approach this? I hope Owa_Util.Redirect_Url function is still supported in latest version. Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

```
APEX_UTIL.REDIRECT_URL('f?p=' || v('APP_ID') || ':106:' || v('SESSION'));
```

[oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35127/GUID-D5A736C6-BA1E-41B5-AF95-D43AC9805D2F.htm#AEAPI2324)

Comment: What error message are you receiving when using the apex_util package?

Comment: No error message. It is not redirecting to the next page. The page is simply refreshing and staying in same page

Comment: What is the page number that it is redirecting to?

Comment: It is not redirecting anywhere. It stay in the same page

Comment: @Crazy2crack which page is the "same page"?

Comment: Login page. Actually 101